# Python graph dfs, bfs solving returns runtime error

Tags: python, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

I try to solve [this problem](https://www.acmicpc.net/problem/1260), but my code returns a runtime error.
I tried with many changes, but I don't know where returns runtime error exactly.
I need some advice or some special cases please...

```py
graph = {}
visited = None

not_visited_vertex = -1
visited_vertex = 1

def dfs(u):
    stack = [u]

    while stack:
        this = stack.pop()
        if visited[this] == not_visited_vertex:
            visited[this] = visited_vertex
            print(this, end=' ')

            for i in sorted(graph[this], reverse=True):
                if visited[i] == not_visited_vertex:
                    stack.append(i)

def bfs(u):
    from collections import deque
    q = deque()
    q.appendleft(u)

    while q:
        this = q.pop()
        visited[this] = visited_vertex
        print(this, end=' ')

        for i in sorted(graph[this]):
            if visited[i] == not_visited_vertex:
                visited[i] = visited_vertex
                q.appendleft(i)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    n, m, v = map(int, sys.stdin.readline().rstrip().split())

    for i in range(m):
        v1, v2 = map(int, sys.stdin.readline().split())
        if v1 not in graph:
            graph[v1] = []
        graph[v1].append(v2)
        if v2 not in graph:
            graph[v2] = []
        graph[v2].append(v1)

    visited = [not_visited_vertex for _ in range(n+1)]
    dfs(v)

    print()
    visited = [not_visited_vertex for _ in range(n+1)]
    bfs(v)
```

Comment: Are you executing the script from a console or from an IDE? In either case the exception thrown should be written to the console, with a stack trace. This will tell you the line of code that caused the problem.

Comment: There is no error with given test cases in my local. But error thrown from that site's system..

Comment: May I suggest adding some logging and exception handling. If you just wrap everything under __name__ in a try except block, then in the except part, catch the exception and write it to a log file. This should give you stack trace and the type of exception thrown. To test this functionality, just  put something like

[][1]
(an Index Error)

anywhere in your script

Comment: @ds4940 I'll try this, thank you!